# Line execute before Ajax Success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax function and i called that function in another place.But Before success function fires execute the next line in the call place.

### Ajax Call

```
    function NewsLoadNumber(news) {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(number) {
           alert("abc"); <-- thisone fires after.
           return number;
        }
    });
}
```

and then i  called this function in another place,

```
var number = NewsLoadNumber(news);
alert(number); <-- This one fires first as undefined
```

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous so next function doesn't wait for it and fires first

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek how can i solve it ?

Comment: @TechGuy Read the duplicated question. It tells you *exactly* how to deal with this kind of problem.